# Why does MySQL not use a hash table for UNIQUE indexes?

Tags: mysql

I am wondering about the performance impact of a `UNIQUE` index in MySQL. I [read](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html) that these use a B-Tree algorithm behind the scenes, just like normal indexes, but I am trying to understand why.

My thought process: The database already knows that there can only be a single record with a given value, so it can use a hash table to optimise reads and writes to O(1) time complexity instead of O(log n).

Please let me know if I am completely off here.

Comment: O(1) is bogus.  @nbk discusses this further.  In reality Hash is between O(1) and O(N).  BTree is a relatively constant O(log N).  MySQL started out "lean and mean"; hence there was no justification for _both_ BTree and Hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hashes can cause problems

1. Collisons

   A collision is when two different data values produce the same hash value.

   Like shown [here](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2017/01/10/probability-of-secure-hash-collisions/) the probability is actually quite high with increasing numbers.
2. Size and resources

   To have almost no collisions, you need a huge size to save all values.  [Check this article](https://leventov.medium.com/hash-table-tradeoffs-cpu-memory-and-variability-22dc944e6b9a) if you want to know more. The article also describes the problem of the higher CPU power you need to manage that size of data,  plus you need more time to insert data.

The use of  a balanced tree has it perks, but in the middle it is a very good choice, because of it relatively small size, to search, insert ,delete:  O(log n) [as shown here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree).

In [this link](https://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=5990991) you find an idea of an implementation, so you can test it for yourself.